# Assign a specific machine SID to a new Windows installation using Sysprep

Tags: windows, sysprep

I want to script-build a development system from fresh Windows installation media as if it were a Linux container. In this case I need every Windows system I build to share the same machine SID.

According to [explanation](https://serverfault.com/a/1070138/966733) by @AntonTykhyy this is done in the following manner:

1. Fresh installation media is created with chained `Unattend.xml` files where the first file calls single `sysprep /generalize /oobe /unattend:C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Second_Unattend.xml> /shutdown` command using `Microsoft-Windows-Setup-Shell/FirstLogonCommands` Windows Component in `pass 7`
2. When Sysprep finishes and computer shuts down the Windows Registry `SYSTEM` (from `C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`) hive should be loaded offline (using `regedit.exe` executed from Windows PE or different method)
3. Bit 2 should be set to `1` in value `OperationFlags` of key `SYSTEM\Setup\SetupCl\PendingRequest` of the offline hive, i.e. `REG_DWORD` should be changed from hexadecimal `0x00007f0f` (`01111111 00001111` which is set by default) to `0x00000004` (`0100`)
4. New **"binary"** value `SidAccountDomainNew` should be added to `SYSTEM\Setup\SetupCl\PendingRequest` registry key with the value of SID in **"binary form"** of 24 bytes long (the 8-byte fixed length header and 4 32-bit sub-authorities)

I have completed steps 1-3 successfully and I get new random machine SID every time. However I absolutely cannot figure out step 4. I have examined SID documentation ([one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-components), [two](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab), [three](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid)) but whichever type of value I specify for `SidAccountDomainNew` - `REG_BINARY` or `REG_DWORD` - and whichever value I set I absolutely cannot get it to work (`Install Windows` dialog appears after reboot with this message `Windows could not complete installation. To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation`).

My best guess the 8-byte header of `SidAccountDomainNew` is `S-1-5-21` in binary (`01010011 00101101 00110001 00101101 00110101 00101101 00110010 00110001` using [online ASCII text-to-binary converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-binary.html)) and that's it. I re-educated myself on binary ([bits and bytes](https://youtu.be/Weyv-V8xz0c) and [32-bit numbers](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/others/BinNumReps.html)) but cannot get the numbers to fit in 24 bytes specified by @AntonTykhyy.

According to my research there's absolutely no documentation on this matter on the Internet and `SetupCl.exe` is completely undocumented. The only source of knowledge is information provided by [@AntonTykhyy](https://serverfault.com/users/364317/anton-tykhyy) but I cannot comment in his question to ask for an example on how the `SidAccountDomainNew` should be set correctly for i.e. `S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420` (also he mentions 4 sub-authorities so the correct SID might be `S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420-something` because [Microsoft's article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) says sub-authorities are tree blocks of digits 1-2-3 that follow `S-1-5-21-`, so it's unclear what are 4 sub-authorities of 32-bits).

I have also found [this SID explanation](https://neroblanco.co.uk/2018/04/inside-kerberos-sids-tickets-and-tokens-part-2/) which makes my assumptions regarding first 8 bytes of header incorrect, I guess:

> The common way to write a SID is in the form S-1-5-21-xxx, or S-R-I-S…
> Where the first S is a literal to identify that this is a SID, the R
> is the revision number, and so far there has only been revision 1, the
> I is the identifier authority, and then the last S is the subauthority
> which can theoretically be repeated up to 15 times, although for
> Windows it’s repeated only 5 times. So for a standard Windows
> computer or domain SID it would look like
> S-1-5-21-aaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-ccccccc-ddddddd.
>
> Internally within Windows a SID is stored as a variable array of 32
> bit integers, typically for a total of 28 bytes. The first integer
> stores the revision, the count of number of sub-authorities, and the
> identifier authority. This is then followed by however many
> sub-authorities are in this SID. These sub-authority integers are
> stored in little-endian format meaning that the least significant byte
> is stored first, and explains why we have to do a complex
> transformation to get from the integers to the more common S-1-5-21-*
> format.

To summarize, I ask for an example of assigning specific SID `S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420` for machine using  `OperationFlags` and `SidAccountDomainNew` after executing `sysprep /generalize`, specifically what type of the `SidAccountDomainNew` value should be used and what actual user input is required.

SID `S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420` example will do since according to [article](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/others/BinNumReps.html) the 32-bit representation of 86420 decimal is known to be `000000000000000 10101000110010100` - this might save answer writing time (if it's relevant data at all).

P.S. I'm also not sure if setting `OperationFlags` to hexadecimal `0x00000004` is required because hexadecimal `0x00007f0f` (`01111111 00001111`) has bit 2 set too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the format of the 8-byte header. According to [the `SID` structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid), the header consists of 1 byte for the SID format version, 1 byte for the number of subauthorities, and 6 bytes (one [`SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid_identifier_authority)) for the authority. In "S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420", the 1 is the version, the 5 is the authority, and each remaining component (including the 21, in contradiction of several articles!) is a subauthority. Then one field at a time, the numeric representation (bytes written in hex here) of this SID is:

- `01` for the version (1)
- `04` for the number of subauthorities (4), which is not written explicitly in the textual SDDL form
- `00 00 00 00 00 05` for the authority (5), in big-endian order unlike the subauthorities
- `15 00 00 00` for the first subauthority (21)
- `94 51 01 00` three times, for the last three subauthorities (each 86420)

To more easily convert a SID to numeric format, you can use PowerShell!

```
#                                                         ↓ Change to your desired SID ↓
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new('S-1-5-21-86420-86420-86420')
$bytes = [array]::CreateInstance([byte], $sid.BinaryLength)
$sid.GetBinaryForm($bytes, 0)
$bytes | Format-Hex
```

Writing those 24 bytes as a `REG_BINARY` value named `SidAccountDomainNew` worked for me on Windows 10 2004 Enterprise. I didn't have to change `OperationFlags` because, as you said, its data already had bit 2 set.

Comment: Dear @BenN, I'm truly grateful for this comprehensive answer that features in-depth explanation and a valuable PowerShell script! Everything you explained works as advertised in Windows 10 version 21H2 as well. Thank you so much sir for your time, knowledge & expertise!